# optimizing SQL counts

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, mysql-dependent-subquery

I have to select a list of Catalogs from one table, and perform counts in two other tables: Stores and Categories. The counters should show how many Stores and Categories are linked to each Catalog.
I have managed to get the functionality I need using this SQL query:

```sql
 SELECT `catalog`.`id` AS `id`,
       `catalog`.`name` AS `name`,
       (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM `category`
              WHERE `category`.`catalog_id` = `catalog`.`id`
               AND `category`.`is_archive` = 0
               AND `category`.`company_id` = 2
       ) AS `category_count`,
       (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM `store`
              WHERE `store`.`catalog_id` = `catalog`.`id`
               AND `store`.`is_archive` = 0
               AND `store`.`company_id` = 2
       ) AS `store_count`
  FROM `catalog`
 WHERE `catalog`.`company_id` = 2
   AND `catalog`.`is_archive` = 0
 ORDER BY `catalog`.`id` ASC;
```

This works as expected. But I don't like to perform sub-queries, as they are slow and this query may perform badly on LARGE lists.. Is there any method of optimizing this SQL using JOINs?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this a lot faster by refactoring the dependent subqueries in your `SELECT` clause into, as you mention, `JOIN`ed aggregate subqueries.

The first subquery you can write this way.

```sql
                SELECT COUNT(*) num, catalog_id, company_id
                  FROM category
                 WHERE is_archive = 0
                 GROUP BY catalog_id, company_id
```

The second one like this.

```sql
                SELECT COUNT(*) num, catalog_id, company_id
                  FROM store
                 WHERE is_archive = 0
                 GROUP BY catalog_id, company_id
```

Then, use those in your main query aas if they were tables containing the counts you want.

```
SELECT catalog.id,
       catalog.name,
       category.num category_count,
       store.num store_count
  FROM catalog
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) num, catalog_id, company_id
              FROM category
             WHERE is_archive = 0
             GROUP BY catalog_id, company_id
       ) category  ON catalog.id = category.catalog_id
                  AND catalog.company_id = category.company_id
  LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT COUNT(*) num, catalog_id, company_id
              FROM store
             WHERE is_archive = 0
             GROUP BY catalog_id, company_id
       ) store  ON catalog.id = store.catalog_id
               AND catalog.company_id = store.company_id
 WHERE catalog.is_archive = 0
   AND catalog.company_id = 2
 ORDER BY catalog.id ASC;
```

This is faster than your example because each subquery need only run once, rather than once per catalog entry.  It also has the nice feature that you only need say `WHERE catalog.company_id = 2` once. The MySQL optimizer knows what to do with that.

I suggest `LEFT JOIN` operations so you'll still see catalog entries even if they're not mentioned in your category or store tables.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are fine, but you can simplify your query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.catalog_id) as category_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM store s
        WHERE s.catalog_id = s.id AND
              s.is_archive = 0 AND
              s.company_id = c.company_id
       ) AS store_count
FROM catalog c
WHERE c.company_id = 2 AND c.is_archive = 0
ORDER BY c.id ASC;
```

For performance, you want indexes on:

- `catalog(company_id, is_archive, id)`
- `store(catalog_id, company_id, is_archive)`

Because of the filtering in the outer query, a correlated subquery is probably the best performing way to get the results from `store`.

Also note some changes to the query:

- I removed the backticks.  They are unnecessary and just clutter the query.
- An expression like `c.id as id` is redundant.  The expression is given `id` as the alias anyway.
- I changed the `s.company_id = 2` to `s.company_id = c.company_id`.  It seems like a correlation clause.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot use `... OVER ... PARTITION BY ...` because it seems like this syntax isn't supported in MariaDB v10.1.47

Comment: Window functions have been supported since MariaDB 10.20.0, released in May 2017 -- four years ago.  You might want to consider updating.